# having difficulties with saving an image link to a file on my server?

Tags: php

I want to be able to save a link such as

```
example.com/get.php?id=4
```

I want to be able to save this link as an image on the server?

this is so that i can send the temp file to facebook api to upload it to the users profile :)

Thanks

Comment: You want to *take a screenshot of the site behind that URL*?

Comment: nope its my site but im storing images in a database and i need to save the image to file so i can send it to facebooks api

Comment: I think you just need to *POST the image data* to the Facebook API. There's no need for physical files at all. Your question may be better formulated as "how to post images to Facebook?"

Comment: So what problems are you having saving and image from your own site?

Comment: do you want to download the image to your server and then upload to FB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$img = file_get_contents("example.com/get.php?id=4");
file_put_contents("temp_photo.jpg",$img);
```

of course you may have to add some validation.

Other option is to use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to download the image .
Then you can upload the downloaded image to FB.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to take a screen snapshot of a web page displayed in a browser, the manual way to do it is to use Firefox and the FireShot add-on.

After you have installed Firefox and Fireshot:

- Surf to the URL
- Right click on the web page
- Menu will come up
- FireShot >> Capture Entire Page And...
- Save